# How can I change data series dynamically in HighCharts without overwriting initial series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

New to HighCharts.  I have a column chart and I want to be able to plug various subsets of my business data into the columns.  For this test, my data series are:

```
const originalData = [
    {y:0.033, color:'red'},
    {y:0.025, color:'yellow'},
    {y:0.161, color:'green'},
    {y:0.116, color:'purple'},
    {y:0.665, color:'blue'}
];
const alternateData = [
    {y:0.665, color:'red'},
    {y:0.025, color:'yellow'},
    {y:0.116, color:'green'},
    {y:0.161, color:'purple'},
    {y:0.033, color:'blue'}
];
```

In my chart, one series is defined:

```
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        data: originalData
    }]
```

Elsewhere on the page (outside of the chart) I have some links the user can click to check out the alternate data set.  A command like `chart.series[0].setData(alternateData)` changes the chart to the second data series, but then the reverse (`chart.series[0].setData(originalData)`) does not change it back to the original data!  Because the data is passed by reference, I guess, the first switch to `alternateData` overwrites the `originalData` array with the alternate data values.

I have tried cloning the data sets by assigning `[...originalData]` and `[...alternateData]` as the series, but it doesn't solve my problem (maybe because the array has Object values???).  Is there a better way to solve this problem?  **In sum: how can I swap data series in my HighCharts chart, without overwriting the original data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are totally right. Highcharts for performance reasons mutates the original data array. You can return your data from a function to prevent mutations.

```
const getOriginalData = () => [
        {y:0.033, color:'red'},
        ...
];
const getAlternateData = () => [
        {y:0.665, color:'red'},
        ...
];

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: getOriginalData()
    }]
});

// later update
chart.series[0].setData(getAlternateData());
// next update
chart.series[0].setData(getOriginalData());
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3Lkyhqv8/

**Github thread:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4259

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue aswell. My solution was to remove the series that is to be updated and the create a new one:

```
chart.series.remove()
chart.addSeries({
  data: alternateData
})
```

Comment: Can't beat that solution for simplicity!